# Changing an encoding while change Content-Type

Tags: nginx, encoding, mime-types, cherrypy

I have a server, which should response for some requests. Requests contain "Content-Type" is equal to "application/x-protobuf", so I need to response a set of bytes (serialised proto object). When I tried to send this bytes with Content-Type "text/plain" - each byte was successfully delivered to users, but when I tried to change this value to "application/x-protobuf" - every byte with value more than 128 was replaced by \uFFF8.

I use cherrypy framework for my server.

Anybody have some ideas, why this happens? And how to know which encoding were used in case "text/plain".

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Well, probably this is not nginx issue. Only if you are not using `charset` and `charset_types application/x-protobuf` in nginx config.

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr You were right, the problem is not in the nginx. I've ran small cherrypy service, just to check if the problem in the cherry, and yes, bytes are changed, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Google Protocol Buffers code generator for nginx module developers
`https://github.com/dbcode/protobuf-nginx`